# How to set default date in Symfony html5 datepicker?

Tags: symfony, datepicker, symfony-forms

How to set default date for symfony html5 form widet from the controller ?

```
$date = date(d-m-Y); //todays date

...
    ->add('starts', 'date', [
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        'placeholder'=>$data,
    ])
...
```

**'placeholder'=>$data** does nothing. After page is loaded my form input contains dd.mm.yyyy

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
      ->add('starts', 'date', [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'data' => new \DateTime()
        ])
```

Comment: @GlupiJas
I tested it on Symfony 3 - chrome exacly like below and it worked

`->add('starts', DateType::class, [
'widget' => 'single_text',
'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
'data' => new \DateTime(),
'mapped' => false
])`

Comment: Perhaps you  are right but something prevent it from working in my project. Does it work in Syfony 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is linked to a model object, set your date on that object.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had to create an associative array that holds the name of the field and its default value. I had to pass that array to the createFormBuilder() method as a first parameter.

```
$defaultData = [
    'starts' = new \DateTime()
];

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData, ['attr'=>['novalidate'=>'novalidate'])
->add(...)
...
```

I could also set first parameter to ***null*** and add default data using:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['attr'=>['novalidate'=>'novalidate'])
->add(...)
->getForm();
$form->setData($defaultData);
```

this also worked for me.